# Substituir todos os dados de uma coluna de um data frame no R

Tags: data.frame, r, dataframe

Supondo que eu tenho o seguinte data frame (apenas um exemplo, pois o meu tem quase 200.000 linhas):

```
ae <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

be <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

pnadc1 <- data.frame(ae,be)
```

Eu preciso substituir todos os valores das linhas da coluna **ae** pelo número **200**.
Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando esses dados

```
ae <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
be <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

pnadc1 <- data.frame(ae,be)
```

Você pode reatribuir valores dessa forma

```
pnadc1$ae <- 200
```

Saída

```
    ae be
1  200 10
2  200  9
3  200  8
4  200  7
5  200  6
6  200  5
7  200  4
8  200  3
9  200  2
10 200  1
```